# How to dynamic edit a table using a JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I'm trying to set delete buttons on each row of my table in order to let users to delete some rows of the table. However i'm having a terrible time to remove this rows dynamic and remove the data from database... ( no idea how to use the button onclick from html with jsp )

I decided to use some javascript inside the Jsp which did the tricky to remove the row but now i can't delete the entry from the database...

I would like to know if there is anyway to delete data from the database using the javascript and what should be the easiest way to do it ?

Comment: Using JS you may remove table row from DOM and then (but it had better  put some loading GIF image when user clicks on DELETE button) you can send AJAX request on your server to remove record from DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use JavaScript then you'll need to send an [AJAX](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CG8QFjAD&url=http://www.ajaxtutorial.net/&ei=d2YqUKHUOvOb1AWQkoCYCw&usg=AFQjCNHXp7-p1rqKz7MENLbxkhJVmvN9sw) request to your server and then remove the row from the view upon success of the previous action.

For an easy and simple approach to AJAX you can try [PrototypeJS](http://www.prototypejs.org/). However, if you'd like to have really fancy dynamic features you may be more interested in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Without knowing more from your project, I'd suggest to use a [Servlet](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/index.htm) in the server side to receive the AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use [Ajax](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/ajax/) with `div` and `InnerHTML`. `Onclick` to the `Remove` button I will one `javascript` function which will make a call to server with `unique id` to delete the record from database , when we get response back I will hide innerHTML representing that row based on `div Id`.